# Google Slides Error

Tags: java, google-slides-api

I am new to Google Slides API.

I followed the steps in their QuickStart example at https://developers.google.com/slides/quickstart/java and that runs fine.

I am now trying to create a presentation by following the steps at https://developers.google.com/slides/how-tos/presentations and getting the following error when running the code.

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
```

This occurs when I try to create the presentation. Any ideas how to resolve this?

All the best

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

Notice [this](https://developers.google.com/slides/how-tos/presentations#creating_a_blank_presentation) part of the documentation.

> You can also create a blank presentation using the Google Drive API
>   [`Files.create`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create)
>   method, specifying **application/vnd.google-apps.presentation** as the
>   mimeType. You'll need an appropriate [Drive API
>   scope](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/copy#auth)
>   to authorize this call. You'll need an appropriate Drive API scope to
>   authorize this call.